# EF lambda where a collection property intersects an array of ids

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

having an entity with a many to many Property, and an array of selected ids like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public ICollection<Bar> { get; set; }
}

var ids = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }; // selected Bar ids
```

I needed to query `Foos` where `Foo.Bar` has all the `ids`

My attempts:

```
var res1 = cx.Foos.Where(f => ids.All(id => f.Bars.Select(b => b.Id).Contains(id)));
```

works without EF, with EF I get error:

> The LINQ expression ...  could not be translated. Either rewrite the
> query in a form that can be translated

```
var count = ids.Count();    
var res = cx.Foos
         .Where(f => f.Bars.Select(b => b.Id).Intersect(ids).Count() == count)
         .ToArray();
```

also works without EF, but with EF I get error:

> Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'parameter')
> at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda(Expression body, String name, Boolean tailCall, IEnumerable`1 parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```cs
var count = ids.Count();    
var res = cx.Foos
    .Where(f => f.Bars.Count(b => ids.Contains(b.Id)) == count)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: @buga then `>=` should do the trick (unless of course there are duplicate ids in `Bars`)

Comment: actually `==` is correct, I didn't pay enough attention the first time I looked, Thank You;
(I was doing something similar before but with Select instead of Count)